# Comparing attributes of two Json Objects

Tags: json, jackson

Hi I have a scenario where i need to compare attributes of two JSON objects, and if they are the same i want to append the value of one attribute to another one, is it possible to do it in this way?

ex:
JsonObject1

{
"FirstName" :

}

JsonObject2
{
"FirstName: "X"
}

Now since JsonObject2 has "X" and both Json objects have the same attribute i want to append "X" to FirstName in JsonObject1

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
A = { name: null, age: 15 }; 
B = { name: "tom", age: 15 };

for (var key in A) {
    if (A[key]) {
        // all ok A already has a good value
    } else if (key in B) {
        // replace value in A with the one from B (possibly another bad value)
      A[key] = B[key];
    }   
}

console.log(A);
// outputs { name: "tom", age: 15 }
```

This assumes A has all keys of B and that no value is 0 or elsewhat that should evaluate to false in the if clause.